# How to count element in JSON and remove its duplicate with python

Tags: python, json

I have below code to count the element in JSON and remove its duplicate.
My problem is when it need to read thousand line of data, this code take long time to finish.
Can anyone help me if we have better way to do this?

```
#count json element
BattleAmount = []

    for i in DATA:
        amount = DATA.count(i)
        j = copy.deepcopy(i)
        j['md']["amount"] = j['md']["amount"] + amount
        BattleAmount.append(j)
    print("Number of BattleAmount are ", len(BattleAmount))
```

```
#remove duplicate
    duplicates=[]

    for i in BattleAmount:
        if BattleAmount.count(i)>1:
                if i not in duplicates:
                    duplicates.append(i)
```

JSON as this format
`[{"_id": {"$oid": "SL"}, "md": {"mana": 24, "rule_set": "Standard", "amount": 12}, "team": {other dict here}`

full JSON structure as below
[image]
thank you

Comment: why are you using `copy.deepycopy`? this method is slow and that's likely contributing to the code taking a long while to run as mentioned.

Comment: I want to amend this ``"amount": 12`` with the duplicate count.  
``i['md']["amount"] = i['md']["amount"]  + amount`` don't work as remaining duplicate item also affected
Eg. ``''amount": 12`` repeated 3 time, without ``copy.deepcopy`` result will be ``"amount" : 15,"amount": 14, "amount": 13``.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the order of your elements in BattleAmount you can just use set() function

```
unique_elements = set(BattleAmount)
```

Comment: I got this error when using ``set``. ``Exception has occurred: TypeError
unhashable type: 'dict'``

Comment: BattleAmount is a list no? (I deduced it from your append)

Comment: The set function should be called instead of the loop on BattleAmount

Comment: i got this error ``Exception has occurred: TypeError
unhashable type: 'dict'`` too